# jQuery waiting until one animation has finished prior to starting another

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a set of tabs which cause certain DIVs with options to 'fly out' over the top of a parent DIV.  The content is pulled in via AJAX.

The fly outs are called on click like so

```
$('.fly_out').live('click', function() {

    var $widget = $(this).closest('.widget');

    var $flyOutIndex = $(this).index('.fly_out');

    if ($flyOutIndex == 0) {
        $flyOutURL = 'Content/HTMLSnippets/Flyouts/Priceassessment/product_order.htm';
    } else if ($flyOutIndex == 1) {
        $flyOutURL = 'Content/HTMLSnippets/Flyouts/PriceHistory/price_history_comparisons.htm';
    } else if ($flyOutIndex == 2) {
        $flyOutURL = 'Content/HTMLSnippets/Flyouts/PriceHistory/price_history_scenarios.htm';
    } else if ($flyOutIndex == 3) {
        $flyOutURL = 'Content/HTMLSnippets/Flyouts/PriceHistory/price_history_analysis.htm';
    }

    // Close any open flyouts
    closeFlyout();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: DashboardApplicationRoot + $flyOutURL,
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {

            $($widget).prepend(data);

            $('.fly_container').animate({ 'right': '0' }, 'fast');

            $('.scroll').jScrollPane();

            $('.striped li:nth-child(even)').addClass('odd');
        }
    });

    return false;

});
```

I have a function to close the flyouts:

```
function closeFlyout() {

    $('.fly_container').animate({
        'right': '-332'
    }, 'fast', 'swing', function() {
        $(this).detach();
    });

};
```

Which is called when another fly out tab is clicked and also when clicking a close button contained within the fly out itself:

```
$('.fly_container .close').live('click', function() {

    closeFlyout();

    return false;

});
```

I would like to extend this so that if a fly out is open and a user clicks to initialise another flyout, then  the open flyout animates shut but the new fly out waits for this animation to finish before showing the new fly out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a global var that signals if a flyout is open? Then use a timer to invoke the click event until the animation completes.

```
//Global space

var flyOutActive = false;


//Close Function

function closeFlyout() {

    $('.fly_container').animate({
        'right': '-332'
    }, 'fast', 'swing', function() {
        $(this).detach();
//update active flag
flyOutActive = false;

    });

};


//Ajax call

$('.fly_out').live('click', function() {

if(flyOutActive)
{
  //Recursive function call  waits for animation to complete
  setTimer($('.fly_out').click(),100)

}
else
{
    var $widget = $(this).closest('.widget');

    var $flyOutIndex = $(this).index('.fly_out');

    if ($flyOutIndex == 0) {
        $flyOutURL = 'Content/HTMLSnippets/Flyouts/Priceassessment/product_order.htm';
    } else if ($flyOutIndex == 1) {
        $flyOutURL = 'Content/HTMLSnippets/Flyouts/PriceHistory/price_history_comparisons.htm';
    } else if ($flyOutIndex == 2) {
        $flyOutURL = 'Content/HTMLSnippets/Flyouts/PriceHistory/price_history_scenarios.htm';
    } else if ($flyOutIndex == 3) {
        $flyOutURL = 'Content/HTMLSnippets/Flyouts/PriceHistory/price_history_analysis.htm';
    }

    // Close any open flyouts
    closeFlyout();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: DashboardApplicationRoot + $flyOutURL,
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {

            $($widget).prepend(data);

            $('.fly_container').animate({ 'right': '0' }, 'fast');

            $('.scroll').jScrollPane();

            $('.striped li:nth-child(even)').addClass('odd');

             flyOutActive = true;
        }
    });

    return false;
}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

how about if you add an

```
if(.fly_out:animated) { 
   //  do something if it's already animated 
} else {
   //do the action if it's not animated
}
```